# Kendo Grid not Binding to My WCF Service

Tags: json, wcf, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, wcf-data-services

Basically, here is an example of my data that is returned by the web service:

```
{
   "d":
   [
      {
         "__type":"MyDataItem:#MyProject.SomeSpace.Data",
         "Format":"msw12",
         "Id":"0900d60b8712e4ea",
         "LastModifiedBy":"",
         "LastModifiedDate":null,
         "Name":"Jeff's tax document",
         "Size":12727
      },
      {
         "__type":"MyDataItem:#MyProject.SomeSpace.Data",
         "Format":"pdf",
         "Id":"0900d60b8714b1d8",
         "LastModifiedBy":"",
         "LastModifiedDate":null,
         "Name":"Bob's Test File",
         "Size":11911784
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is my Kendo Grid code. It loads, calls the service, but then has an error:

```
<div id="example" class="k-content">
   <div id="grid"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {

          $("#grid").kendoGrid({
              dataSource: {
                  type: "odata",
                  transport: {
                      read: "http://localhost:4567/Services/MYSERVICE.svc/GetListing",
                      dataType: "json"
                  },
                  schema: {
                      data: "d"
                  },
                  pageSize: 10,
                  serverPaging: true,
                  serverSorting: true
              },

              scrollable: {
                  virtual: true
              },
              height: 250,
              selectable: "row",
              columns: [{
                  field: "d.Name",
                  title: "Name"
              }, {
                  field: "d.LastModifiedDate",
                  title: "Last Modified"
              }, {
                  field: "d.Size",
                  title: "File Sized",
              }, {
                  field: "d.LastModifiedBy",
                  title: "Last Modified By"
              }]
          });
      })

   </script>
</div>
```

The error I see in Chrome is:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

However, that error is in reference to the json data that comes back and it is all on one line so it doesn't help me find it.

I noticed that my data coming back from the service has a "d" at the beginning of it at a root node. The other examples of json data I have seen online have been much more simple and didn't have this root node on them. We might be able to update the service to return the data differently if need be. I just want to know how to edit my kendo code to put this stuff up on the grid. I can research and tweak it after that I think.

Do I need the "d." reference in the columns declaration? I think I might have that part wrong.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Have you tried removing the `d.`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a few problems. You have specified 'odata' but your service doesn't appear to be OData end point. Then you have set `dataType` as a transport option which it isn't - it is an option of `transport.read`. Last you need to remove the `d` from the field names of the columns.

Here is how the fixed configuration should look like:

```
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
          dataSource: {
              transport: {
                read: {
                  url: "http://localhost:4567/Services/MYSERVICE.svc/GetListing",
                  dataType: "json"
                }
              },
              schema: {
                  data: "d"
              },
              pageSize: 10
          },
          scrollable: {
              virtual: true
          },
          height: 250,
          selectable: "row",
          columns: [{
              field: "Name",
              title: "Name"
          }, {
              field: "LastModifiedDate",
              title: "Last Modified"
          }, {
              field: "Size",
              title: "File Sized",
          }, {
              field: "LastModifiedBy",
              title: "Last Modified By"
          }]
      });
```

And a live demo: http://trykendoui.telerik.com/@korchev/IGah

Answer (score 3):

Yes - remove the "d." in your columns definition. From the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.data), an example:

```
<script>
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/twitter/search",
      dataType: "jsonp", // "jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests; use "json" for same-domain requests
      data: { q: "html5" } // search for tweets that contain "html5"
    }
  },
  schema: {
    data: "results" // twitter's response is { "results": [ /* results */ ] }
  }
});
dataSource.fetch(function(){
  var data = this.data();
  console.log(data.length);
});
</script>
```

The data: "results" just tells kendo that the array is contained in the object results. The column definition should not contain results.Column1, results.Column2, just Column1, Column2, etc...

```
columns: [{
                  field: "Name",
                  title: "Name"
              }, {
                  field: "LastModifiedDate",
                  title: "Last Modified"
              }, {
                  field: "Size",
                  title: "File Sized",
              }, {
                  field: "LastModifiedBy",
                  title: "Last Modified By"
              }]
```

Also, another issue I ran into later was with the count being wrong when doing server side paging. This was because I was missing the "total" element. The "total" element should return the TOTAL number of elements (not just the returned # of elements - if you are doing server side paging).

From the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.total)

> If schema.total is not specified the length of the Array returned by
>   schema.data will be used. **The schema.total option must be set if the
>   serverPaging option is set to true**.

**Example**

```
<script>
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    /* transport configuration */
  }
  serverGrouping: true,
  schema: {
    total: "total" // total is returned in the "total" field of the response
  }
});
</script>
```

**All together now**

```
<div id="example" class="k-content">
   <div id="grid"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {

          $("#grid").kendoGrid({
              dataSource: {
                  transport: {
                    read: {
                      url: "http://localhost:4567/Services/MYSERVICE.svc/GetListing",
                      dataType: "json"
                    }
                  },
                  schema: {
                      data: "d",
                      total: "totalCount"
                  },
                  pageSize: 10,
                  serverPaging: true,
                  serverSorting: true
              },

              scrollable: {
                  virtual: true
              },
              height: 250,
              selectable: "row",
              columns: [{
                  field: "Name",
                  title: "Name"
              }, {
                  field: "LastModifiedDate",
                  title: "Last Modified"
              }, {
                  field: "Size",
                  title: "File Sized",
              }, {
                  field: "LastModifiedBy",
                  title: "Last Modified By"
              }]
          });
      })

   </script>
</div>
```

**What you should return**

```
{
   "d":
   [
      {
         "__type":"MyDataItem:#MyProject.SomeSpace.Data",
         "Format":"msw12",
         "Id":"0900d60b8712e4ea",
         "LastModifiedBy":"",
         "LastModifiedDate":null,
         "Name":"Jeff's tax document",
         "Size":12727
      },
      {
         "__type":"MyDataItem:#MyProject.SomeSpace.Data",
         "Format":"pdf",
         "Id":"0900d60b8714b1d8",
         "LastModifiedBy":"",
         "LastModifiedDate":null,
         "Name":"Bob's Test File",
         "Size":11911784
      }, /* ..... 8 other items if you are doing 10 per page ... */
   ],
   "totalCount": 534
}
```

**EDIT**
Good catch Atanas, I missed that jsonp part. I have updated this code, and modified your code a little to adding serverPaging. Note: The server paging doesn't actually work as you have no backend logic to handle the paging, but the "count" element has been added. Should get you started.

http://trykendoui.telerik.com/uNIX

Comment: Hi Jac. Thank you for the excellent response! The "totalCount"... you are saying that the service needs to return that as a last piece of information on the end of the stream there as your example shows?

Comment: Also worth noting. I am still receiving the same error. Since I am unable to change the WCF Service to bring back "totalCount" at the moment, I decided to take out paging just to see if this would work. So I took out pageSize, serverPaging, serverSorting, and totalCount from your example and it still gave me: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: See edits, Atanas was right, I missed something else